# Scaling existing regression coefficients to predict for different dataset

Tags: r, regression, normalization, scaling, prediction

I am tasked with coming up with a way to project customer activity for different groups of customers for 60 months. These groups can be based on a multitude of factors - plans, acquisition channel, month of acquisition etc. i.e. whatever criteria the end user needs to use. I am learning as I go and I thought the best approach would be to develop a model based on 60 months of completed data for a few different customer groups using regression. The model can then be applied to different customer groups that the end user is interested in.

The model seems to work well in most cases but there are groups that just have a different level of purchase activity. So for example, my model is based on data where customers spend an average of $15 every month. However, there are a few customer groups where the average spending is $5, due to which the projections are way off. Typically, the model is run with 2-3 months of data of the customer group.

Is there a way to "scale" the coefficients so that the model projects fairly well for different groups with different spending levels? This is more of a stats question.. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to post example data and do a better job of explain the analysis you have already done. Without those items I predict your question will be closed for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, youre building a regression model using data where the average spend is $15, but now you're trying to use that model to predict outcomes for a different group where the average spend is $5, and this is throwing your predictions off?

The reason this happens is because your model specification is wrong. The correct way to handle this is to include both the $15 and $5 groups when you're building the regression model (i.e. train with all the data). You shouldn't use regression to train on one population, and then to test on another because you're just applying the wrong model to your target population (the $5 group)

If for some reason you can't rebuild your model using data from all groups of interest, another thing you could try is building a standardized model with just the $15 group. I'm not sure how well this works in practice, you'll have to build the model and test it, but it would go something like this:

Take your $15 group data and standardize the predictor variables by taking each value, subtracting the mean of that variable, and then divide by the standard deviation: `X_standardized = (X - mean(X))/sd(X)`

Use those standardized predictors to build a new regression model.

Once you have your new model and you want to predict values for, say, the $5 group, instead of passing in the raw $5 values for prediction, you would have to first standardize the variable, and pass in the standardized value.

This is not going to work if you're trying to predict one value at a time and don't have access to a large enough sample of $5 group members to calculate a mean and standard deviation.